# Anaconda3 Pythonw.exe Ordinal 242 could not be located in the dynamic link library libiomp5md.dll

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I initially actually tried to install Tensorflow and Keras for R Studio. 
I followed the instructions online. I installed Python 64bit first and then installed Anaconda. 
First, it worked for a while. Then I was trying to install Tensorflow GPU version. Somehow, it got this weird problem.

If I tried to run code associated with TensorFlow or even trying to open Spyder IDE. This error message pops up.

I have tried uninstalled both Python and Anaconda many times. No success. What did I do wrong? Please help. Thank you so much, guys.

[image]

Comment: Anyone? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by myself.

I copied libiomp5md.dll from Anaconda to Windows\system32 directory and it worked. I don't know why but it worked.

Comment: This is why it worked: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#numpy-mkl-library-load-failed